# Free plugin to create/display Photoshop measurement annotations

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, free, plugin, measurement

I found this plugin SpecKing that looks like it's just about exactly what I'm looking for, I haven't tried it out yet though because I was hoping to find a free, maybe even open source alternative..

Does anyone know of any open-source and/or free Photoshop plugins similar to this one?

I'm looking to extend the functionality of the measure tool so as to actually display annotated measurements of the measured distances for convenient reference.. like a blueprint basically.

[image: 202 px annotated measurement]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a shopping-list question.

Comment: I disagree.  I'm looking for recommendations or referrals to a plugin with the aforementioned features which I've been unsuccessful at finding thus far after extensive searching.

Comment: So you're asking others to search or you... thus shopping list. Just my opinion and my opinion alone doesn't carry much weight in the Stack Exchange community model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's this Photoshop script that is free, called **[Pixelmeasure](https://code.google.com/p/pixelmeasure/)**. It's not as complete as SpecKing, **you will need to first make a selection and then run the script to get the measurements.**

[image]

> If you have ever done site mockups in Photoshop and needed to mark
>   these with pixel measurements you know what an incredibly tedious task
>   this can be.
>
> I went looking for a script that would help you automatize this
>   process. Surprised to not find one, I decided to write one myself.

**Installation**

- Download the latest version, unzip and place the Pixel Measure.jsx file in your Photoshop scripts directory (located in /Presets/Scripts).
- Restart Photoshop.

The Pixel Measure script should be visible in the `File > Scripts` menu. You can create a keyboard shortcut to the script using the `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts` menu.

**Usage**

- Make a selection in a document and run the script.
- To create a horizontal measurement - select an area that has a greater width than height, and vice versa.
- The color of the measurement is determined by your current foreground color.
- The line thickness of the measurement is determined by your current pencil settings.

Comment: Thanks.  Have you tried the other (paid) plugin that I mentioned?  I'm about to try out this one you recommended but am just curious if there may be any advantage to buying the other one.  Thx

Comment: This is great actually, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @dcc Good to know! I haven't tried the paid plugin, it looks "easier" to use. But pixelmeasure's shortcuts might come in handy, right? If you want to share how it went feel free to edit the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

[Ink](http://ink.chrometaphore.com/) is a free plugin that will provide spec documentation for your Photoshop document.  It provides layer measurements, text formatting, and layer style information with the option of turning any or all of these on and off.

To install, download and run the Ink plugin from the link above.

Once installed, reopen Photoshop and open the extension by going to Window > Extensions > Ink. Select an object or text layer in your document and press the yellow ink button or text button (respectively) to see your document annotations.

Answer (score 2):

I am a designer and front-end engineer on one design studio, I just used [**Markly**](http://marklyapp.com) to do app design spec, I think it's really cool photoshop spec tool with so many creative functions like smart measure, update spec automatically etc. I inadvertently discovered this post, so I think I should recommend it. And I found it from producthunt: http://www.producthunt.com/posts/markly
[image]

Comment: Hi adotidea, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!