# How to get specs of UI elements from PSD file for IOS?

Tags: interface-design, ios

I'm going to make an IOS app, and I will get interface mockups of my app from a designer. But I don't know in which format he will send me the interface, whether in PSD or JPEG format.

With the given format i want to find all specs like X-Y coordinates, width, height and distance between each element present in the interface in points or pixels.

So, is there any tool to get all the specs? I have searched and found [xScope](http://xscopeapp.com/) but i have not used it yet. Is this tool effective or not? Are there any other free tools?

Comment: x-scope is to measure elements in your computer screen, not necessarily the best tool to get specs from design files (if you zoom in the measurements are invalid). _Ask your designer_, not us.

Comment: Only applicable to PSD but possible duplicate: [Free plugin to create/display Photoshop measurement annotations](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/29541/52050)

Comment: Given this is not asking about a particular format, but could include anything from a hand drawing to a PSD, I'm voting to close this question as too broad

Comment: I also believe this is something you need to ask the designer (and/or agree on), but if you have Photoshop I personally find it quite easy to use the Slice tool to create measuring boxes on top of the stuff. But they are not for coordinates, they would be best for getting widths and heights.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload PSDs in [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), an Open Source Adobe tool. It give you every specs you want and can extract assets directly from the PSD.

As a Web Designer, I don't use it much. But our developers do, and they gave me great feedback about it.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. How does that help getting the specs from the PSD files?

Comment: @Luciano Brackets [can](https://youtu.be/M-Dcf6HhwYM?t=208) extract specs and assets directly from PSDs

Comment: oh ok, my bad. Reverting my vote then