# Is there an automated way to draw pixel measures on an image in GIMP

Tags: gimp, automation, measurement, script

#### Question

Is there an existing plugin or script for GIMP that performs the same function as the pixelmeasure script described below?

#### Background

There is a JSX script for *Photoshop* (*pixelmeasure.jsx*) that allows you to draw pixel measurement rules over your image. This is very useful to keep notes of relative distances of objects in an image.

A version of the *Photoshop* JSX script can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/yorb/5042960

#### How the pixelmeasure script works

1. In Photoshop Use the rectangular marquee tool to select the area you want to measure.
2. Run the script

Features:

- It will draw a rule along the longest dimention of the selection.
- You can alias it to a hotkey to make the process very fast and convenient.
- The rules appear on a separate new layer.
- The font is configurable by editing the script.
- The color of the rule is taken from the current foreground color.

#### Desired output

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Related question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29541/free-plugin-to-create-display-photoshop-measurement-annotations/29542#29542

It doesn't answer my need for a GIMP based tool but does provide alternative solutions.